# How to remove many rows from dataframe using for loops, which iterate through the values that needs to be removed?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I'm trying to remove over several million rows by its name, which is more than 1000 unique values.

There is the main dataframe (df_summary) and another dataframe that contains the name of the rows that must be deleted from the main dataframe.

Removing a few columns is not a problem but the number of unique values needs to be removed are simply too many to execute manually. 
Hence I am trying to loop through it.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBSvF.jpg "overall look of the two dataframes, many columns following the  column"

Following is what I have tried:

```
from pandas import read_csv
import pandas as pd

df_summary = read_csv ('path.csv', sep=',')
rows_to_remove = read_csv ('path.csv', sep=',')

i = 0
for i in range len(rows_to_remove):
    item = df.loc[i].item()
    df_summary = df_summary.drop(df_summary['contract'] == f"{item}", axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)  to create a mask & then use this mask to filter you dataframe (to have only those value or to have values other than those values)

```
m = df_summary['contract'].isin(rows_to_remove['contract'])
df_summary [~m]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It seems to have worked. Would you mind telling me what the symbol ~ is called in terms of pandas and what it does?

Comment: tilda (~) inverses the mask created. With `isin` we are checking which of the rows of df_summary contain values of `rows_to_remove['contract']`. However, since you want to excluded those rows, we use tilda symbol. Print `m` & `~m` & you will get a visual idea of what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

If you iterate through rows, it won't be as efficient as if you used the indexing capabilities of pandas dataframes. I don't quite understand the difference between `df_summary` and `rows_to_remove` in your example since they're both loading the same csv. But let's imagine you have all the values of `df_summary['contract']` that you want removed in a list called `values_to_remove`. Then you can do something like this:

```
# values_to_remove = the list of values you are trying to remove
df_cleaned = df_summary.loc[ ~df_summary['contract'].isin(values_to_remove) ]
```

Answer (score 0):

As a general rule of thumb, most of the time when you're looping over a pandas object you shouldn't be because there's a better way of doing it.

Try this:

```py
df_summary.drop(rows_to_remove.values, inplace=True)
```